# Joining On Different Column Types

Tags: plsql

I'm using a table to drive selects from other tables, e.g.:

```
SELECT A.location_code, 
    A.company_name, 
    B.location_name  
FROM my_schema.tbl_companies A 
LEFT JOIN my_schema.tbl_locations B 
    ON A.location_code = B.location_code
```

That location_code field is numeric (NUMBER) and that's fine for most of the cases I'm working with.  However there are some tables where the location code is defined as VARCHAR2 which would mean I can't join on the location_code foreign key field.  Without altering the composition of the source tables (i.e.: without changing the VARCHAR2's to NUMBER's) what is the best solution here?

Comment: The solution is in your question. You have to cast the varchar to number or number to varchar to get the desired result.

Comment: You mean like this?

    LEFT JOIN my_schema.tbl_locations B
        ON A.location_code = TO_NUMBER(B.location_code)

Comment: Yes. I have converted the id number to to_Char and joined 

select * from mytable1 m inner join mytable1 a
on m.name = to_char(a.id)